# Can you handle a form without creating a new php file?

Tags: php

I want to know if its possible to handle an html form and display the info without creating a new php file. the purpose is so that i could display the data on the same page as the form.

for example I have this form that takes user input for QB name and team. Currently it takes the input and the displays the output to the file nfl.php.
my nfl.php holds my php script.

**HTML**

```
    <form action="phpfiles/nfl.php" method="post">
        Enter quarterback name: <input type="text" name="Qback"><br>
        Enter team name: <input type="text" name="team"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    function nfl(){
            echo  "Quarterback Name: ", $_POST["Qback"];
            echo "<br>";
            echo  "Team Name: ". $_POST["team"];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
    }
    nfl();
    nfl();
    nfl();
    nfl();
    nfl();
?>
```

What I want to know is if I can handle the form and display the output on the same page as my html form, as currently when i click submit, i am redirected to nfl.php and the output is shown. so instead of being redirected i would have

*html form*

unpon clicking submit, the output would be shown below

*html form*

*php output*

hopefully what I am asking makes sense, Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just leave the `action=""` attribute of the form empty.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider so then would i just put my php script below the form?

Comment: it's best if the action has the same php page as the form, not empty. Then in the page, at the bottom of the form, you can check if the post is sended with `if(!empty($_POST)) { /* your code */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do like this?

test.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 
   if(!empty($_POST))
{
    // this block runs only if form is submitted
  echo  "Quarterback Name: ", $_POST["Qback"];
  echo "<br>";
  echo  "Team Name: ". $_POST["team"];
  echo "<br>";
} else
{
  // just show the normal form if user doesn't submit the form
?>
 <form action="" method="post">
        Enter quarterback name: <input type="text" name="Qback"><br>
        Enter team name: <input type="text" name="team"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i ask why you put the php script first and not the form? does it matter?

Comment: If there's a case if you don't want to show form again if user submit a form, then you have to put at top..So, it will check if form is submitted first before showing html form.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: Coool. Updated that scenario above. Accept if it helps, thanks :)

Comment: Fill the action, it's best practice. That's the same code as in my comment in the post xD